# Laplace transform double function

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm trying to find the Laplace transform of the function $$f(t) = \begin{cases}
1, & 0\le t < \pi\\
0, & \pi\le t< \infty
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite $f(t)$ as follows:

$$f(t)=u(t)-u(t-\pi)\tag{1}$$
Now use
$$\mathcal{L}[u(t)]=\frac{1}{s}$$
and 
$$\mathcal{L}[g(t-a)]=e^{-as}\mathcal{L}[g(t)]$$
and the linearity of the Laplace transform to find the laplace transform of $(1)$.

Comment: Hmm, is it possible to create two integrals instead? So that L(f(t)) = int1 + int2, where int1 goes from zero to pi, and int2 goes from pi to infinity?

Comment: $$\mathcal{L}[f(t)]=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-st}dt=-\frac{e^{-st}}{s}\biggr\rvert^{\pi}_{0}=\frac{1-e^{-\pi s}}{s}$$